# Rss feed fails to display data

Tags: java, rss, activemq-classic

I have a project in which i need data from activemq needs to get dispalyed on an rss feed as notification to user showing current status of the program whle running, but somehow the whole process run but the rss feed remains empty and as the process completes then feed dissappears automatically as desired.. the problem is why is the feed empty. I have included the code responsible as follows and the stacktrace as well

when i do a debug, the control jumps from

reader = new XmlReader(url);

to directly if (reader != null)

without going into the entire adding values to list and all, what could be the possible reason.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/rssFeedReader")
public class RssFeedReaderController {

@Value(value = "#{'${activemq.ip}'}")
private String ipaddress;
@Value(value = "#{'${activemq.port}'}")
private String port;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@RequestMapping(value = "/readRssFeeds/{sourceName}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<RssFeedMessage> readRssFeeds(@PathVariable String sourceName) {
    XmlReader reader = null;
    RssFeedMessage rssFeedMessage = null;
    StringBuffer feedUrl = new StringBuffer("http://").append(ipaddress).append(":")
            .append(port).append("/admin/queueBrowse/").append(sourceName).append("?view=rss&feedType=rss_2.0");
    List<RssFeedMessage> rssFeedMessages = new ArrayList<RssFeedMessage>();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(feedUrl.toString());

        reader = new XmlReader(url);

        SyndFeed feedMsg= new SyndFeedInput().build(reader);

        List<SyndEntry> feedEntries = feedMsg.getEntries();
        for (SyndEntry entry : feedEntries) {
            rssFeedMessage = new RssFeedMessage();
            rssFeedMessage.setTitle(entry.getTitle());
            rssFeedMessage.setDescription(entry.getDescription().getValue());
            rssFeedMessage.setDate(OptimerUtil.simpleDateHourTimeInd.format(entry.getPublishedDate()));

            rssFeedMessages.add(rssFeedMessage);

        }
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FeedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    return rssFeedMessages;
}
}
```

this is the stack trace: the initial lines `java.io.IOException:           Invalid     Http response
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1343)
    at com.sun.syndication.io.XmlReader.<init>(XmlReader.java:174)
    at com.sun.syndication.io.XmlReader.<init>(XmlReader.java:151)
    at com.optimer.util.RssFeedReaderController.readRssFeeds(RssFeedReaderController.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`